# Lost connection to MySQL server during query just on MacOS

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I have an SQL query with 2 subqueries. whenever I run it on MySQL Workbench on macOS, it gives "Error Code: 2013. Lost connection to MySQL server during query". However, when it runs on Workbench on Windows, it runs normally without any errors. 
I tried to increase the connection timeout, but still no success! 
Any clue on how to solve this issue? 
I appreciate your support and cooperation.

**here is a query that gives an error:**

```
with t1 as(

SELECT s.name rep_name, r.name region_name, sum(o.total_amt_usd) as total_amt

FROM sales_reps s

JOIN accounts a

ON a.sales_rep_id = s.id

JOIN orders o

ON o.account_id = a.id

JOIN region r

ON r.id = s.region_id

group by 1,2),

t2 as(

select region_name, max(total_amt) as total_amt

from t1

group by 1)

select t1.rep_name, t1.region_name, t1.total_amt

from t1

join t2

ON t1.region_name = t2.region_name AND t1.total_amt = t2.total_amt;
```

Comment: Does it happen only with subqueries?

Comment: first, thanks for your response.
I have written the query that gives the error! when I run this query on windows machine, it works normally. however, it gives this error when I run on MacOS.
moreover, if I just remove "sum" function from the first subquery (t1), it would run normally as well. just when I add "sum" or "count", it gives this "lost connection" error!

Answer (score 2):

Your query is taking too long to return data so the connection gets dropped. There are 2 ways to fix this issue.

(i) Optimize query

(ii) Increase MySQL timeout

Explaining 2nd way:

```
1. In the application menu, select Edit > Preferences > SQL Editor.
2. Look for the MySQL Session section and increase the DBMS connection read time out value.
3. Save the settings, quite MySQL Workbench and reopen the connection.
```

Comment: I tried this way and increased the timeout to 600000, but still gives the same error.
BTW, when I try it on a windows machine it runs normally and gets executed in less than 3 seconds.

Comment: @tmoussa did you try in command line both in windows & mac? It could be workbench specific issue.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I uninstalled the workbench and installed it again and now it is working properly. Thanks for who tried to answer my questions.